# Ruby Shoes: Minimize app to system tray on windows

Tags: ruby, shoes

Does anyone know if it is possible (and if it is, how?) to put a Shoes application in MS Windows system tray?

Something like using minimize to put the window to system tray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

done!
with green shoes, see sample54.rb

Answer (score 2):

A far as I know you'll have to mess with win32api (function Shell_NotifyIcon in shell32).
[This discussion](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/18102) might get you started.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with Shoes, currently.